# How to represent 2 parent child drop down in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 drop down lists, when the user selects dropdown#1 then I need to update dropdown#2 with options that are relevant for the dropdown#1 selection.

e.g.

Dropdown#1 has car manufacturers:  ford, toyota, honda

Dropdown#2 will be cars for that specific manufacturer.

How should I go about storing this data in javascript?

I was hoping I could create a collection like some sort of dictionary or hash so I can populate each drop down easily.

I have the actual data from the database, then on the server-side I will create the JavaScript  I need to create this data structure.

Comment: This has probably been asked a million times already. You have the search function in the upper right corner.

Comment: [Just a search result here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=populate+a+dropdown+by+javascript+depending+on+another+dropdown).

Comment: I don't want to make an ajax call, I want to store all the data client side in a javascript object, I am asking how to structure that data.

Comment: Are you asking what a JavaScript object is supposed to look like? Because it seems you already have everything else planned out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment
`I don't want to make an ajax call, I want to store all the data client side in a javascript object, I am asking how to structure that data`

So just an idea

**HTML**

```
<select id="cars_company">
    <option value="ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
</select>

<select id="cars">
    <option value="ford_car_one">Ford Car One</option>
    <option value="ford_car_two">Ford Car Two</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    cars={
        ford:{
            ford_car_one:'Ford Car One',
            ford_car_two:'Ford Car Two'
        },
        toyota:{
            toyota_car_one:'Toyota Car One',
            toyota_car_two:'Toyota Car Two'
        }
    };

    $('#cars_company').on('change', function(){
        $('#cars').html('');
        $.each(cars[$(this).val()], function(k, v){
            $('<option></option>').val(k).text(v).appendTo($('#cars'));
        });
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tckm2/1/).

​

Answer (score 0):

By a dropdown I suppose you mean a select box. The best way would be to use static javascript , but have it perform a ajax call to pick up the data. The first select box would already be filled with data in the html (that can offcourse be build with a server side script using the data form your database) On the change event of the first select box, you would have the ajax call send the value of that box and based on that you have the server send back the data for the second select box. Than with a little bit of jQuery you could fill the second selectbox with the retrieved data. This is quiet a comon case, so you should be able to find some tut online if you need to...

Comment: I don't want to make an ajax call, I don't have that many options so I can store it all client side during the first page load.

Comment: You said you have server side script as well as javascript, so i don't see why you could not make an ajax call. However, you could indeed send all the data of the second select in the javascript already, stored as multi dimensional array. You would be sending a lot of data that you will never use though...

Comment: It causes things to slow down for no reason, it isn't allot of data that is what I am saying.  5 items for ddl#1, and like 20 in total for ddl#2.